# How to develop using JavaPOS in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javapos

I'm new to [JavaPOS](http://www.javapos.com/). I wanted to create an online Java POS application that uses JavaPOS. Is it possible to access the POS peripherals regardless of the brand? Is it possible that Epson ADK will be enough to access the other brands too? And more importantly, can it be accessible via web?

How do I start coding in JavaPOS in Eclipse? I found a paper about deployment ([JavaPOS deployment](http://www.javapos.com/downloads/JavaPOS-Deployment_20040212.pdf)), but it doesn't say anything about development. I also found some examples but I do not know how to set it up in eclipse? Where do I put the `jpos.xml` in the first place? I already did the health check, and it's ok.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839049/how-can-i-use-javapos-to-print-reciepts-with-an-epson-printer/30839050#30839050

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs I found are not suffiecient. I found a github repository that uses JavaPOS in his project. I just checked it out and it somehow works. https://github.com/emigonza. Thanks to emigonza and his examples I have a headstart.

Answer (score 5):

According to [javaPOS site](http://www.javapos.com/public.app.guide.10.html), there is a *JavaPOS v1.10 Guide for Application and Device Programmers*, which as of version, 1.10, is

> The JavaPOS v1.10 Guide for Application and Device Programmers is now
>   available from the [Arts Website](http://www.nrf-arts.org/), located within the UnifiedPOS v1.10
>   specification.

following this link leads to nothing ... and a search in Arts website *yielded no results*. A dead end ? Not so sure ...

One can easily find

- A [JavaPOS FAQ](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/41083511/JavaPOS-FAQ-pos-software)
- A [JavaPOS driver kit manual](http://www.toshibatec-eu.com/upl/default/default/doc/ST-B10_JavaPOSDriverKitOperationManual_1st.pdf)
- [Java for retail POS prgrammer's manual v 1.6](http://www.javapos.com/downloads/JPOS_Version_1_6.pdf)

I guess it's enough as a start, no ?

Comment: Arts Website leads to a dead end. I already tried looking there.

Comment: @user9507 ok, but the other links ?

Answer (score 2):

[UnifiedPOS Spec](https://nrf.com/resources/retail-technology-standards/unifiedpos) (have to register there to download)

Check **"*Appendix B*: Java for Retail POS — JavaPOS Implementation Reference"** . This is the JavaPOS Development Guide. This is actually as good as you are ever going to get regarding development for JavaPOS, at least that I know of.